# How to restart Windows services including their depending ones using `net stop` or `sc stop`?

Tags: windows, services

For various reasons I need to restart the service `NLA (Network Location Awareness)` or `NlaSvc` on the shell using an automated task. Doing so manually using `services.msc` shows a dialog telling me that some other service is depending on this one and asking if I want to restart ALL of those. Using `net stop NlaSvc` on the shell behaves the same, while using `sc stop NlaSvc` ends with an error only.

```
C:\windows\system32>net stop NlaSvc
Die folgenden Dienste hängen vom Dienst NLA (Network Location Awareness) ab.
Das Beenden des Dienstes NLA (Network Location Awareness) beendet auch diese Dienste.

   Netzwerklistendienst

Möchten Sie diesen Vorgang fortsetzen? (J/N) [N]: N

C:\windows\system32>sc stop NlaSvc
[SC] ControlService FEHLER 1051:

Ein Stoppzeichen wurde an einen Dienst gesendet, von dem andere Dienste abhängen.
```

The problem with `net stop` is that I didn't find a way to answer the question automatically and couldn't get `sc` to e.g. simply forward the command to all depending services as well. The only workaround I currently have is some custom script stopping and starting the individual services because I know their names already.

So, is there something with `net stop` or `sc stop` resolving those dependencies automatically that I have just missed? Something like a force-mode or alike? Or is that only available for [Powershell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-service?view=powershell-7.1#parameters) using `stop-service -force`.

Comment: Have you tried to check what dependent service causes the message to appear? I tried that on my PC, NLA starts and stops from powershell with no problems or questions. No windows service should interact with the user in any way. This is a serious bug / abuse of system service pattern. Find the offending service, uninstall it (or at least get a fixed version) and it should work as expected.

Comment: It's not the service directly interacting with the user, but the apps `net` or `services.msc` instead. Things depend on what you have done exactly with PowerShell, e.g. if provided `-force` or not. Without that an error message should be printed as well, because `netprofm` aka `Netzwerklistendienst` depends on `NlaSvc`. PowerShell doesn't change anything on that.

Comment: No system service should depend on any interaction. It's in a definition of Windows Service. It provides Start and Stop methods. System controls them (or a user via sc or control panel). However - a service can (if no one will stop it) run an application as user and that particular application is a problem here. Commands like `sc` or `net` (AFAIK) don't have "force" option, because it is not needed for services. BTW, it works on my Windows 10. I can start and stop both nlasvc and netprofm. No questions asked.

Comment: Look for other service that depends on NLA. It looks like an external program might have installed an invalid service, that ask a question on its stop handler. This is, as you can see - system breaking behavior, because it breaks normal service controller operation. System assumes the service is broken (non-responding) and just gives up to stop it. I wonder what happens on machine restart or shutdown.

Comment: Using "net stop servicename /y" will usually stop a service and it's dependencies while confirming the prompt automatically (note the extra "/y" parameter in the example). Unluckily this does not work for "NlaSvc"...#

Comment: `/y` was what I was looking for. Where did you get it from? I don't see it documented in the help of `net` itself. Is something similar available for `sc` as well? Most likely doesn't work because `netprofm` has depending services as well. Though, this is the answer I was looking for, so you should provide it.